# How do convert below code from T-SQL into DB2 LUW?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

How do I convert this code from T-SQL into DB2 LUW, it seems so easy with T-SQL but in DB2 can't find any solution. See code below:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)

SET @columnList = 'AddressID, AddressLine1, City'
SET @city = '''London'''
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM Person.Address WHERE City = ' + @city

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: Provide more details, format the code and tell us how you are executing that code.

Comment: Actually, my goal here is how to put an SQL Statement  like the code above @sqlCommand in DB2 LUW then Execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can’t ‘select to nowhere’ in a compound statement in DB2. Db2 CLP can return you the result set of a single sql statement, but it doesn’t try to do the same for select statements in a compound statement. If you want to print the result set from a select statement in a compound statement, you can, for example, declare a cursor, fetch it in a loop, and use [dbms_output.put_line](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053539.html) calls to print the values of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not Pretty but you can find an example of the bottom of this page:
 [Stored Procedures and Dynamic SQL Returning a Result set](https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/183025-db2-stored-procedures-dynamic-sql-returning-result-set)

Essentially you most:

1) create a dynamic SQL string
  2) prepare the string into a statement 
  3) Link the statement to a cursor you're going to declare as WITH RETURN

Opening the cursor will be the last line in your procedure.